# Analogies of a combination of Newton's and Coulomb's law interpreted in Hilbert sphere in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-state

I wanted to share with you something I stumbled upon about Hilbert spaces and Newton's formula for gravitation.
Newton's formula for gravitation is represented by
$$
F_N(a,b) \cdot r/|r| = G \cdot \frac{m_a \cdot m_b }{| x_a - x_b|^2}.
\cdot r/|r| $$
However, this can be equivalently expressed as

$$k(a,b) := \exp\left( -|x_a-x_b|^2 \right) = \exp\left( -\frac{ G m_a \cdot m_b }{ F_N(a,b)} \right)$$

which is known as the radial basis function kernel (RBF kernel by the [Moore-Aronszajn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space#Moore%E2%80%93Aronszajn_theorem) ) and has applications in machine learning and statistics.
Interestingly, $k(a,b)$ can be shown to be the inner product $\langle a,b\rangle$ to an infinite dimensional Hilbert space, specifically the Hilbert Sphere:
$$
S_\infty = \{ x \in H \mid k(x,x) = \langle x,x\rangle = 1 \}.
$$
By solving the last equality for $F(a,b)$, we can define the force in any Hilbert sphere with inner product $k(a,b)$ for $a \neq b$ as:
$$
F_N(a,b) := - \frac{G m_N(a) \cdot m_N(b) }{ \log( k(a,b) )},
$$
where $m_N(x)$ denotes the mass of $x$.
Additionally, from a physics standpoint, the geodesic distance in Hilbert sphere is given by $\arccos(k(a,b))$, which results in
$$
d(a,b) = \arccos \exp\left( -|x_a-x_b|^2 \right)  = \arccos\exp\left( -\frac{ G m_a \cdot m_b }{ F(a,b)} \right).
$$

First let us look at the situation where two material bodies $a,b$ which might posses mass, electric charge and magnetic charge, which exert force on each other, by the Newtons gravity law and Columb's law for electric charges and magnetic charges. By Newton's law, we can build the sum of these forces:

$$F(a,b) \cdot r/|r| = (F_N(a,b) + F_C(a,b) + F_M(a,b) ) r/|r|$$

which is equal to:

$$F(a,b) \cdot r/|r| = (\mu_N(a)\mu_N(b)G+\mu_C(a)\mu_C(b)k_e+\mu_M(a)\mu_M(b)k_m)/|x_a-x_b|^2)\cdot r/|r|$$

and this might be written as:

$$F(a,b) \cdot r/|r| = \frac{\left < \mu(a),\mu(b)\right>}{|x_a-x_b|^2} \cdot r/|r|$$

which again might be written as:

$$F(a,b) = -\frac{\left < \mu(a),\mu(b)\right>}{\log(k(a,b))}$$

where we have put:

$$\mu(x) = (\mu_N(x),\mu_C(x),\mu_M(x))$$

and here $\mu_N(x),\mu_C(x),\mu_M(x) \equiv $ mass, electric charge, magnetic charge, $k(a,b) := \exp( - |x_a-x_b|^2)$ and
$$\left < \mu(a),\mu(b) \right> := \mu_N(a)\mu_N(b)G+\mu_C(a)\mu_C(b)k_e+\mu_M(a)\mu_M(b)k_m$$
is an inner product on the 'measurable quantities' mass, electric charge and magnetic charge.

Observe also, that by puting two of the quantities to $0$ the other quantity will give the force previously started with.

We observe that the function:
$$k(a,b) = \exp(-|x_a-x_b|^2) $$
is indeed a positive definite function, since it is a Gaussian kernel, which is known to have this property.

As mentioned, in $S_{\infty}$ the shortest path metric is given by:

$$d(a,b) = \operatorname{arccos}(k(a,b))$$

With this we can rewrite:

$$F(a,b) = -\frac{\left < \mu(a),\mu(b)\right>}{\log(\cos(d(a,b)))}$$

The function $f(x) = -\frac{1}{\log(\cos(x))}$ has for $x=0$ by Wolfram Alpha the following Laurent series representation:

$$\frac{2}{x^2} - \frac{1}{3} - \frac{x^2}{30}+O(x^4)$$

So we get in the limiting case where $a$ moves very close to $b$:

$$\lim_{a \rightarrow b} F(a,b) = \lim_{a \rightarrow b} -\frac{\left < \mu(a),\mu(b)\right>}{\log(\cos(d(a,b)))} = $$
$$ = \lim_{d(a,b) \rightarrow 0} -\frac{\left < \mu(a),\mu(b)\right>}{\log(\cos(d(a,b)))} $$
$$\approx 2 \frac{\left < \mu(a),\mu(b)\right>}{d(a,b)^2}$$

which looks similar to Newton's law of gravity, but with the difference that the distance is measured on the Hilbert sphere.

**Analogies to quantum mechanics:**

1. In quantum mechanics, is there the "Fubini-Study distance" which gives the shortest path in Hilbert sphere between two pure states:**

$$d(a,b) = \operatorname{arccos}(\left < \phi(a),\phi(b) \right >_H) $$

which is also used here.

2. In QM and in the situation discussed here, Hilbert spheres are used:

   pure states correspond to vectors on Hilbert sphere.

   position vectors in this situation correspond to vectors in Hilbert sphere.

**Question: Is there any more analogies from Quantum Mechanics which would make sense in the situation presented here?**

Thanks for your help!

Related:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445804/machs-principle-newtons-law-and-hilbert-sphere

https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/132ytl6/hilbert_space_formulation_of_newtons_gravity_law/